# javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes.put() method: is there a way to create an LDAP entry with 2 identical LDAP attributes at creation time?

Tags: java, ldap

I tried using the javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes.put() method.  However, when I run the code (see sample below) I only get 1 attribute value in the "testKey1" LDAP attribute ("junk1"), instead of 2 (i.e. "junk1" and "junk2")?

How can I do this on an ldap create call?

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide

```
/**
 * Creates an LDAP ENTRY based on a commonName passed in.
 * 
 * @param commonName
 * 
 * @throws NamingException 
 */
public void createLDAPEntry (String commonName) 
        throws NamingException
{
    Ldap ldap = null; // a custom Ldap object that can be used to connect and perform methods on an Ldap connection (i.e. create, add, delete, etc.).

    try
    {
        ldap = getLDAPAuthenticated(true); // bind to LDAP with the appropriate credentials

        String commonNameString = "cn=" + commonName + "ou=Servers,ou=myOrg,c=US";

javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes basicAttributes = new BasicAttributes(true); // new object with case-insensitive

// basicAttributes.put(new javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute("cn", commonName)); 
// not needed, the ldap.create() does this for you.

        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("testKey1", "junk1"));
        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("testKey1", "junk2"));

        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("sn", commonName));
        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("objectclass", "top"));
        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("objectclass", "person"));
        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("objectclass", "organizationalPerson"));
        basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("objectclass", "inetorgperson"));

        ldap.create(commonNameString, basicAttributes); // will create a cn that has commonNameString for the value and the attributes

    }
    finally
    {
        // be sure to close the connection 
        if (ldap != null)
        {
            ldap.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding create method call

```
protected void create(String dn, javax.naming.directory.Attributes attrs) throws NamingException
{

    LdapContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
        int i = 0;

        while ((i <= this.config.getOperationRetry())
                || (this.config.getOperationRetry() == -1))
        {
            try
            {
                ctx = getContext();
                ctx.createSubcontext(dn, attrs).close();
            }
            catch (NamingException e)
            {
                operationRetry(ctx, e, i);
            }
            ++i;
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        if (ctx != null)
            ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled like crazy to get this but have you tried using the add method?

Example code (creating DNS replies):

```
Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
attr = new BasicAttribute("PTR");
attr.add(0, "eg-www.apple.com.");
attr.add(1, "www.apple.com.");
attrs.put(attr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a BasicAttribute and put two values into it. If you look at the Javadoc you will see that your second BasicAttribute with the same name replaces the first one.

Comment: I'm looking at this:
[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/BasicAttributes.html#put(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object) )

While the javadoc says that it "adds" a value, it actually seems to be "replacing the value" if one already exists?

Comment: `basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("testKey1", "junk1"));  
basicAttributes.put(new BasicAttribute("testKey1", "junk2"));`

The problem is that only "junk2" is in there, and replaces "junk1" rather than adding a 2nd "basicAttribute". 

Your comment doesn't tell me anything new unless there's something I'm missing?

Comment: @EJP as the OP, I also have been unable to use BasicAttributes.put(). Instead I had to use BasicAttribute.add() (as per comment above).

Comment: @AndredeMiranda Well the Javadoc leaves no doubt that a new attribute with the same name replaces the old attribute value, and returns it, just like `Map.put()` really.

Comment: @EJP I get it. Yet it is possible to have add two values to the same key as per response above. Give it a go and you will not be surprised that the same key may have two values (a Vector of values to me more precise).

Records like that are quite commonly generated by JNDI's DNS query implementations where response contains more than one record